# Why are there the following $2$ sequences for $A^3-(A-1)^3 -7 \bmod 7 = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Why are there the following $2$ sequences for $A^3-(A-1)^3 -7 \bmod 7 = 0$?

Here is $A^3-(A-1)^3$:

$2^3-1^3, 3^3-2^3, 4^3-3^3, 5^3-4^3, 6^3-5^3, 7^3-6^3...$

Equal to:

$7,19,37,61,91*,127,169,217**,271,331,397,469*,547,631,721**,817,919,1027,1141*,1261,1387,1519**,1657,1801,1951,2107*,2269,2437,**2611,2791,2977,3169,3367*,3571,3781,3997**...$

**The first sequence** is made of the numbers marked as $*$ and starting with $91$ and  will occur every seven places, including:

$91, 469, 1141 ,2107, 3367...$

Growing at:

$378, 672, ,966 , 1260...$

Growing at:

$294, 294, 294...$

**The second sequence** is made of the numbers marked as $**$ and starting with $217$ will occur every seven places, including:

$217, 721, 1519 ,2611, 3997...$

Growing at:

$504, 798 ,1092 , 1386...$

Growing at:

$294, 294, 294...$

I am aware that there is probably a general rule for $A^x-(A-1)^x - B \bmod B =0$, but I thought it would be easier for me to explain my question with the specific case of $A^3-(A-1)^3 -7 \bmod 7 = 0$:

I think I understand why they grow every seven places, but:

Why are there $2$ sequences? Why are they staring at  $91$ and $217$? What does the final growing rate of $294$ (for both) represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if $f(x)$ is a non-zero degree $d$ polynomial, then there at most $d$ solutions.

Note that the extra $-7$ and $-B$ are unnecessary in your equation.

In this case $A^3-(A-1)^3 \equiv 3A^2-3A+1 \equiv 3(A-2)(A+1) (\mod 7)$, so this will be divisible by $7$ exactly when $A \equiv -1,2 (\mod 7)$. This causes your two observed sequences.

In your general question for $A^x-(A-1)^x$, there are at most $x-1$ solutions $\mod p$. Whether there are that many and what they are depend upon $x$ and $p$.

Additionally, applying repeated differences to sequences just gives polynomials of a smaller degree. In particular, differences in $x^3$ have leading term $3x^2$. Differences in those have leading term $6x$, whose differences are $6$. The terms in your sequence are $7$ apart, so the above differences are $6*7$ apart, so they two above differences are $6*7*7=294$ apart.

Also, your second sequence actually starts at $7$. They are just the smallest numbers satisfying the congruence.